# "DEFAULT" section with no values in config text file

Tags: python, default, configparser

Why there is a section named "DEFAULT" but with no values in my config text file?

I have a text file "policy.txt" with my configurations in it.
So I was running a simple configparser code in Python which looks like this:

```
>>> from configparser import ConfigParser
>>> config = ConfigParser()
>>> config.read('policy.txt')
['policy.txt']
>>> for key in config:
...     print(key)
...
```

The numbers you see (1 to 5) are the section names in my policy.txt file.  This is the result:

```
DEFAULT
1
2
3
4
5
```

So I was wondering what is stored in "DEFAULT" section. Then I ran this code segment:

```
>>> for key in config['DEFAULT']:
...     print(key)
...
...
>>>
```

But it seems like the section isn't storing anything. So **why is it there in my policy.txt file?**

Any helpful idea is appreciated.

Comment: I think this is explained in the [documentation of ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - What is the intended use of the DEFAULT section in config files used by ConfigParser? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124692/what-is-the-intended-use-of-the-default-section-in-config-files-used-by-configpa)

Comment: @user202729 yeah, checked on that link before. It showed windows.ini file. But mine is text file. Not sure if it correlates.

Comment: @Kiki I think you should state more clearly the fact that the default section is not actually in your file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFAULT` is a “special” section that is always present in a `ConfigParser` instance. It stores [fallback values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#fallback-values) that are used as defaults when a value in another section is missing.

If you want to iterate over the sections in your configuration and want to exclude the default, use `sections()`:

```
>>> for key in config.sections():
...     print(key)
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
```